# Как подождать 5 секунд перед загрузкой модального окна bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Как подождать 5 секунд перед загрузкой модального окна bootstrap на сайте? 
Знаю что можно сразу при загрузки страницы вывести, но как подождать 5 секунд и затем вывести модальное окно не знаю. Пробовал интервал брать `setTimeout()` , но не помогает.

```
$(window).load(function(){        
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию setTimeout как в моём примере.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#ex1").modal();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <p>Thanks for waiting. That felt good.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>
<p>Please wait for five secodns...</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!